# ffmpeg truncates output files without return an explicit error

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am transcoding a file with a duration of 1:42:92 using an ffmpeg pipeline. The output file is truncated (its duration is 30 seconds) without any warning about the output file is shorter than the input.
Is there a way of making ffmpeg exit with error in that case?

This is the pipeline:

`ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -y -b:a 64k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 2000k -filter:v scale=w=1280:h=720 -maxrate 2100k -bufsize 10000k -threads 4 -movflags faststart test_hd.mp4`

I can see the folowing errors in stdout:

`frame=  794 fps= 24 q=23.0 q=21.0 q=23.0 q=9.0 q=0.0 q=0.0 size=    7677kB time=00:00:33.47 bitrate=1878.8kbits/s    \r[h264 @ 0x76356a0] AVC: nal size 2322
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x76356a0] concealing 3060 DC, 3060 AC, 3060 MV errors in P frame
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x37235e0] stream 0, offset 0xfc6c7a: partial file
test.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
frame=  806 fps= 24 q=23.0 q=21.0 q=23.0 q=10.0 q=0.0 q=0.0 size=    7802kB time=00:00:33.96 bitrate=1881.9kbits/s    \r[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x37235e0] stream 1, offset 0xfe720d: partial file
test.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x37235e0] stream 1, offset 0xfe74aa: partial file
test.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x37235e0] stream 1, offset 0xfe77a5: partial file
test.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x37235e0] stream 1, offset 0xfe7a11: partial file
test.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
frame=  818 fps= 24 q=23.0 q=21.0 q=23.0 q=8.0 q=0.0 q=0.0 size=    7953kB time=00:00:33.96 bitrate=1918.2kbits/s    \r[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x37235e0] stream 1, offset 0xfe7c7b: partial file
test.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x37235e0] stream 1, offset 0xfe7ec1: partial file
test.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp4 @ 0x381fc40] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=  819 fps= 22 q=-1.0 Lq=-1.0 q=-1.0 q=-1.0 q=-0.0 q=-0.0 size=    8491kB time=00:01:42.92 bitrate= 675.9kbits/s

video:14041kB audio:668kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] frame I:5     Avg QP: 6.17  size: 53165
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] frame P:207   Avg QP:11.84  size: 28073
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] frame B:607   Avg QP:15.44  size:  3820
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] consecutive B-frames:  0.9%  0.5%  1.5% 97.2%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] mb I  I16..4: 62.8% 22.5% 14.7%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] mb P  I16..4:  0.8%  3.1%  1.0%  P16..4: 30.7% 23.4% 16.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:24.6%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 34.2%  4.8%  0.9%  direct: 1.4%  skip:58.6%  L0:40.5% L1:50.4% BI: 9.1%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] 8x8 transform intra:49.5% inter:69.2%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 57.1% 69.6% 59.5% inter: 12.0% 17.0% 2.2%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 72%  8%  6% 14%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 25% 28%  4%  5%  5%  6%  4%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 23% 15%  5%  8%  7%  7%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 61% 18% 17%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] ref P L0: 63.4%  5.6% 22.1%  8.9%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] ref B L0: 90.0%  8.2%  1.8%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] ref B L1: 94.8%  5.2%
[libx264 @ 0x381eb00] kb/s:1968.29`

Comment: You trimmed the console output so important information is missing.